# Progress bar below menu for each link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im looking for help to create a menu like this [This is the menu i want](http://piccsy.com/investors/)

It can be done with Javascript or Jquery?

I did a menu like this with html and css but it's not the same as the website.

I have 2 optiones

this is the 1st code but the problem is if i click on other thing of the website it looses the progress bar...

```
body {
    padding: 10em 0 0;
}
.ui-menu {
    width: 37em;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-menu a {
    width: 4em;
    margin: 0 .15em;
    padding: .1em .35em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    font: 17px "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-menu a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.ui-menu-bottom-line {
    width: 35em;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background: #d7d7d7
        linear-gradient(left, #d82126 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat;
    background-size: 5em;
    transition: 1s; 
}
.ui-menu a:nth-child(2):focus ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line,
.ui-menu a:nth-child(2):active ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 15em;
}
.ui-menu a:nth-child(3):focus ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line,
.ui-menu a:nth-child(3):active ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 25em;
}
.ui-menu a:nth-child(4):focus ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line,
.ui-menu a:nth-child(4):active ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 35em;
}
.ui-menu a:nth-child(5):focus ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line,
.ui-menu a:nth-child(5):active ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 45em;
}
.ui-menu a:nth-child(6):focus ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line,
.ui-menu a:nth-child(6):active ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 55em;
}
.ui-menu a:nth-child(7):focus ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line,
.ui-menu a:nth-child(7):active ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 65em;
}
```

and HTML :

```
<div class="ui-menu">
<a class="goto-frame" href="#" tabindex="1">Welcome</a><a class="goto-frame" href="#" tabindex="1">Problem</a><a class="goto-frame" href="#solution" tabindex="1">
Solution</a><a class="goto-frame" href="#team" tabindex="1">Team</a><a class="goto-frame" href="#traction" tabindex="1">Traction
</a><a class="goto-frame" href="#product" tabindex="1">Product</a><a class="goto-frame" href="#contact" tabindex="1">Contact</a>
<div class="ui-menu-bottom-line"></div>
```

SECOND CODE:

```
body {
    padding: 10em 0 0;
}
.ui-menu {
    width: 37em;
    padding: 0;
    font: 17px "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-menu input[type=radio] { display: none; }
.ui-menu label {
    width: 4em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .1em .5em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-menu-bottom-line {
    width: 35em;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background: #d7d7d7
        linear-gradient(left, #d82126 50%, transparent 50%) no-repeat;
    background-size: 5em;
    transition: 1s;
}
.ui-menu #welcome:checked ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 5em;
}
.ui-menu #problem:checked ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 15em;
}
.ui-menu #solution:checked ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 25em;
}
.ui-menu #team:checked ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 35em;
}
.ui-menu #traction:checked ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 45em;
}
.ui-menu #product:checked ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 55em;
}
.ui-menu #contact ~ .ui-menu-bottom-line {
    background-size: 65em;
}
```

AND THE HTML:

```
<div class="ui-menu">
<input type="radio" name="mi" id="welcome">
<label class="goto-frame" for="welcome">Welcome</label>
<input type="radio" name="mi" id="problem">
<label class="goto-frame" for="problem">Problem</label>
<input type="radio" name="mi" id="solution">
<label class="goto-frame" for="solution">Solution</label>
<input type="radio" name="mi" id="team">
<label class="goto-frame" for="team">Team</label>
<input type="radio" name="mi" id="traction">
<label class="goto-frame" for="traction">Traction</label>
<input type="radio" name="mi" id="product">
<label class="goto-frame" for="product">Product</label>
<input type="radio" name="mi" id="contact">
<label class="goto-frame" for="contact">Contact</label>
<div class="ui-menu-bottom-line"></div>
```

How can i do a menu like piccsy.com/investors ??  Javascript? Jquery? HTML+CSS??

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install firebug or inspect element to see how things is done. In this case,  your progress bar contains 2 things: a grey line, and a red line (actual a div) above it. When you scroll or click the navigation, there will be a script to change red bar width so you can see a progress.
So your script must handle 2 things: scroll event and click on nav event.

Example:

```
function updateProgress(){
   $('#progress').width(maxWidth * ($(body).scrollTop() / $(body).height()) );
}

$('#Nav1').click(function(){
   //Scroll to a position
   $(body).scrollTo(100);
});

$(body).scroll(function(){
   updateProgress()
});
```

something like that

Comment: This is the live example of 1st code :
http://dabblet.com/gist/3155730
And this for the 2nd code:
http://dabblet.com/gist/3155806

Comment: So what is the problem? It runs fine with me

Comment: I want to do it with jQuery not with CSS